Android PagingSource keeps loading data and returns infinitely
I am implementing a fetch doctor application which loads dynamically doctor data objects from an api with a retrofit call and presents them in a LazyVerticalGrid in the mainActivity. I am utilizing a PagingSource class which with the overriden load method is supposed to return paged results. However it appears that the code infinitely returns the result of the load method.
In the viewModel:
class DoctorViewModel(private val repository: DoctorRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _doctors = mutableStateOf<List<Doctor>>(emptyList())

    private val _doctorsFlow = MutableStateFlow<PagingData<Doctor>>(PagingData.empty())
    val doctorsFlow: StateFlow<PagingData<Doctor>> get() = _doctorsFlow

    var doctorSpecialty = mutableStateOf<String>("")
    var userLatitude =  mutableStateOf<Double>(0.0)
    var userLongitude =  mutableStateOf<Double>(0.0)
    var radius = mutableStateOf<Int>(25000)

    var currentPage by mutableStateOf(1) // Hold current page in ViewModel

    suspend fun getDoctorsBySpecialty()
    {
        val query = getOverpassQueryForSpecialty(doctorSpecialty.value, userLatitude.value, userLongitude.value , radius.value) // adjust radius and query as needed
        _doctors.value = repository.fetchAllDoctors(query)
    }

    // PagingSource for local pagination over the loaded doctors
    fun getDoctorsPaged(page: Int): Flow<PagingData<Doctor>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 5, // Adjust page size as needed
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { DoctorsLocalPagingSource(_doctors.value, page) } // Pass page
        ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }

and the class DoctorsLocalPagingSource:
class DoctorsLocalPagingSource(private val doctors: List<Doctor>, private val page: Int) : PagingSource<Int, Doctor>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Doctor> {
        val pageSize = 5
        val page = params.key ?: 1
        val fromIndex = (page - 1) * pageSize
        val toIndex = minOf(fromIndex + pageSize, doctors.size)

        println("Loading page $page with fromIndex $fromIndex to toIndex $toIndex")

//the code keeps returning here:
        return if (fromIndex < doctors.size) {
            val pageItems = doctors.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = pageItems,
                prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (toIndex < doctors.size) page + 1 else null
            )
        } else {
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = emptyList(),
                prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = null
            )
        }
    }


    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Doctor>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }
}

In my main activity i have the DoctorsScreen composable method which is responsible for presenting the list of doctors i acquire from the viewModel:
    @Composable
    fun DoctorScreen(viewModel: DoctorViewModel) {
        // Use remember to keep the current page state stable
        var currentPage by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
        var isDoctorsLoaded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        // StateFlow to hold PagingData and initialize with an empty PagingData

        val doctorsPagingFlow = remember { MutableStateFlow(PagingData.empty<Doctor>()) }

        var lazyPagingItems : LazyPagingItems<Doctor> = doctorsPagingFlow.asStateFlow().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
        // State variable to hold lazyPagingItems, initializing with an empty list

        var column_items = remember {
            mutableStateOf(lazyPagingItems)
        }
        // Trigger fetch when current page changes
        LaunchedEffect(currentPage) {
            viewModel.getDoctorsBySpecialty()
            isDoctorsLoaded = true
        }

        // Initialize lazyPagingItems only when doctors are loaded
        if (isDoctorsLoaded)
            lazyPagingItems = viewModel.getDoctorsPaged(currentPage).collectAsLazyPagingItems()

        // Create a derived state that updates whenever lazyPagingItems changes
//        val columnItems by remember {
//            derivedStateOf { lazyPagingItems }
//        }


            LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)) {
                // Check for item count before rendering
                    items(count = lazyPagingItems.itemCount,
                          key = lazyPagingItems.itemKey { it.id },
                        contentType = lazyPagingItems.itemContentType { "contentType" }
                    ) { index ->
                        var doctorItem = lazyPagingItems[index]
                        if (doctorItem != null) {
                            DoctorListItem(doctorItem)
                        }
                    }


                // Pagination loading indicators
                lazyPagingItems?.apply {
                    when {
                        loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading -> {
                            item { CircularProgressIndicator() }
                        }

                        loadState.append is LoadState.Loading -> {
                            item { CircularProgressIndicator() }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Pagination controls
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        if (currentPage > 1) {
                            currentPage--
                        }
                    },
                    enabled = currentPage > 1
                ) {
                    Text("Previous")
                }

                Text("Page $currentPage")

                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        currentPage++
                    },
                    enabled = lazyPagingItems.itemCount >= 5 // Adjust based on your page size
                ) {
                    Text("Next")
                }
            }
}

Any idea of why does the code exhibit this behaviour in the PagingSource?
Thank you for your input.
